# ERROR: venv: commands failed while installing devstack on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, openstack, python-2.7

I am trying to install `devstack` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
While installing I came across this error. Up to this I edited the `local.conf` file and installed `libvirt-1.2.15`.
The detail screenshot is as follows:-

```
venv create: /opt/stack/tempest/.tox/venv
venv installdeps: -r/opt/stack/tempest/requirements.txt, -r/opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt
venv develop-inst: /opt/stack/tempest
venv runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1819679666'
venv runtests: commands[0] | verify-tempest-config -uro ../../../tmp/tmp.rVlU7KbPiF
Running config verification...
**ERROR: InvocationError: '/opt/stack/tempest/.tox/venv/bin/verify-tempest-config -uro ../../../tmp/tmp.rVlU7KbPiF'
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   venv: commands failed**
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+ /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-05-12-152538.txt for details
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Is `venv`installed?

Comment: hey hi, venv is installed. I checked it by using this                        stack@stack:~$ virtualenv --version
12.1.1                                                                                                                                              Before this, I  run ./stack.sh  file from devstack as given on this following link and I got this error.  link is                                     http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-machine.html

Comment: I am trying to install devstack on ubuntu 14.04 LTS  as a dual boot along with windows 7 on other partition. Does it affect python virtual environment.

Comment: Nope, the windows OS doesn't affect things going on in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and 15.10.